# Webpack + Sails Multi Page application

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, sails.js, webpack

question regarding splitting code with webpack
I have [multipage sails site](https://github.com/MariMax/sailsWebpack), with 3 different pages

First page contains jquery, bootstrap, modernizr and moment

Second page contains jquery and bootstrap

Third page contains jquery, bootstrap and moment

if I use CommonsChunkPlugin it gets jquery and bootstrap in separate module, so I expected that on first page I need to load js related for first page(common+first), on second page only common scripts and on the third page scripts related to third page(common+third)

first and third pages work well, but on the second page I can't open modal window to change language(right top window corner if you run the app)

questions:

1) how may I run bootstrap js on second page, to allow open modal window

2) how to implement lazy loading on each page, obviously I do not need bootstrap on page load, it can wait some time, while user will not press change language link

3) why I cannot use last modernizr, if I remove it from bower.json and run `bower i modernizr --save` it will update modernizr to 3.0, but webpack cannot find it

to run the app, just clone it, set up grunt globally and run `npm i` command, it will start the app on localhost:1337

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere in your second page are you including the script tag to the common chunks.